# Do I need a last `else` clause in an `if...else if` statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Every `if...else if` example I’ve seen includes a final `else` clause:

```
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else if (condition2) {
  doB();
} else if (condition3) {
  doC();
} else {
  noConditionsMet();
}
alwaysDoThis();
```

I understand that this is basically syntactic sugar for nested `if...else` statements:

```
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else {
  if (condition2) {
    doB();
  } else {
    if (condition3) {
      doC();
    } else {
      noConditionsMet();
    }
  }
}
alwaysDoThis();
```

I have never seen any examples of an `if...else if` that **omits the last `else` clause**. But seeing as plain `if` statements (without `else` clauses) are valid, and going by the equivalent “nested statements” above, my gut tells me that this is okay to do:

```
if (condition1) {
  doA();
} else if (condition2) {
  doB();
} else if (condition3) {
  doC();
}
alwaysDoThis();
```

Can someone point me to a resource or example that explicitly says whether or not it’s valid?

And on another level, if it *is* valid, would it be recommended or is it considered “bad practice”?

Comment: Flow control exists for you to decide how to control the flow. Naturally, you can find out if it's "valid" by running the code and seeing it execute.

Comment: It depends on the context. You should *always* consider the `else` case, but often you don't need to handle it explicitly. However, I think the likelihood for the necessity increases with the number of cases. That conforms to your claim that it is unusual to omit the `else` clause in bigger conditional cascades.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on my answer; I learned a [new word](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-mutually-exclusive-events-and-collectively-exhaustive-events).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The ending `else` is not mandatory as far as JavaScript is concerned. As for whether it is needed, it depends on what you want to achieve.

The trailing `else` clause will execute when none of the specified conditions is true. If the conditions are [collectively exhaustive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectively_exhaustive_events), then an `else` clause is entirely superfluous, except possibly to contain an assertion that catches the "impossible" condition. In your case, whether you need an `else` clause depends on whether you want specific code to run if and only if neither of `condition1`, `condition2`, and `condition3` are true.

`else` can be omitted for *any* `if` statement, there is nothing special in the last `if` of an `if`/`else if` chain. This is documented in any JavaScript grammar, e.g. in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5).

Comment: no problem! I understood what you meant, but i wanted to correct the record. You were right that your conditions *should* be **mutually exclusive**, for good coding (even though it's not mandatory). But whether the final `else` clause would ever run doesn’t require your conditions to be mutually exclusive; it requires them to be **collectively exhaustive**. Look up the **MECE Principle** to learn more.

Comment: @chharvey Yes, collectively exhaustive fits exactly what I wanted to communicate - if I'd known the term, I would have used it. Using "mutually exclusive" in its place sort of works because it's a stronger criterion so it doesn't invalidate the rest of the sentence - but collectively exhaustive covers it without being either too strict or too permissive.

Answer (score 20):

**It is 100% valid. No, it is not bad practice.** If you don't need it, don't write it.

Take the following for example:

```
function doStuff(data) {
    if (data.something) {
        // go format the data in some way
    }
    else if (data.somethingElse) {
        // go format the data in some other way
    }
    // must be formatted correctly, don't do anything else
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I was thinking I am doing something wrong by not adding the last else.

Answer (score 15):

You never *need* an `else` clause. (It's hard to offer examples of something that is not necessary, so I'll leave it at that.)

*edit* as a comment notes, square brackets in language syntax notation *usually* indicate that something is optional.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I haven't seen any official documentation. Even [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) always have a final `else` clause.

Comment: However, note that this does not extend to the ternary conditional operator: `a ? b : c` can never become just `a ? b` (but `a && b` has the semantics you'd expect from it).

Comment: @chharvey: From the docs you linked: *"**statement2**
    Statement that is executed if condition evaluates to false and the else clause exists."* They're telling you that the `else` clause may not exist. Also the syntax shows square brackets around `[else statement2]`, which generally indicates something optional.

Comment: Yes I saw the square brackets and I know the `else` in a plain `if` statement is optional; I was just looking to confirm that it was *also* optional in an `if..else if` statement.

Comment: @chharvey: JavaScript doesn't have an `else if` statement. This is also noted a couple times in the docs you linked. It only has `if (expression) statement else statement`. Because an `if` statement is a statement (obviously), you can use it after `else`, just like any other statement, like `for` or empty `;` or `switch` or any arbitrary expression statement.

Comment: user1106925 is simply incorrect. the block `if (expression) statement else statement` is syntactically distinct from the block `if (expression) statement else if (expression) statement`

Comment: @chharvey no `else if` works because `if` satisfies `statement`. There's nothing special about an `if` after an `else`, any more than `for` or `while` or `return` after an `else`.

Comment: @Pointy i disagree. i think the block `if (expression1) statement1 else if (expression2) statement2` is completely distinct from `if (expression1) statement1 else {} if (expression2) statement2`, because in the first case, `expression2` is only evaluated if `expression1` fails. whereas in the second case, `expression2` gets evaluated regardless.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a else block, they are not if else statement but if statements. Consider else, elseif as an extension.

Here's a link to a sitepoint thread : [click this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-if-elseif-without-else/6710).
And a similar thread on stackoverflow : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313706/best-practice-on-ending-if-else-statement-without-else-condition)

Comment: thank you, but even though the principles are the same, this question is about Javascript, not PHP

Comment: oups, wrong section ;)